# Map accuracy assessment by moving window

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I would like to make **accuracy assessment** using confusion matrix between classified Landsat image and reference dataset. Maps have the same resolution and extent. I would like to evaluate the agreement by **pixel-by-pixel**. In many studies I have found that they used **moving-kernel window** (ideal 3x3) to "deal" with the Landsat pixels misregistration. However I couldnt find any approach to do use this moving window for confusion matrix evaluation in R, normally it is used to values interpolation.

Do you have any ideas how to **implement moving window into classification accuracy assessment**? Or am I misunderstanding this approach?

Thanks a lot,

Exemple:

```
library("raster")
clas <- raster(ncols=5, nrows=5)
values(clas)<-c(2,1,0,0,1,
         2,1,0,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0,0,
         2,1,0,0,2)
reference <- raster(ncols=5, nrows=5)
values(reference)<-c(2,1,0,0,0,
         2,1,0,0,1,
         0,0,0,0,0,
         1,2,0,0,2,
         0,0,0,0,0)
```